# What is the most optimal way to massage the huge set of images for classification using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

What is the most optimal way to massage the huge set of images for classification using tensorflow? i have 100gb of images. How can I use them for pre-trained models provided by tf?
Provide the code as well

Below code is taking some time to process.

```
def convert_img_numpy(img_file_name_list):
      img_tensors_list = [(tf.cast(tf.image.resize(tf.constant(mpimg.imread(img)),(224,224)),tf.float32)/255,tf.constant(j)) for img,j in zip(img_file_name_list,label_bool)]
      return img_tensors_list

img_tensor_list = convert_img_numpy(img_list)
```

please provide an optimized version of this code which can run for huge data set.

Comment: Every single code will take "some time". You really should be more specific with your question.

Comment: You're processing 100gb of images, that will take a while. Is there a reason you think it can be done better, other than it currently taking a long time?

Comment: @James Z : Yes every code takes a time.My question is suggest a way to optimize it.

Comment: @samsupertaco: I am not processing 100gb of image now.I have trained it on say 68 mb of data but it took a while to prepare and process it. But in real work scenario data might be enormous so I asked if there i some experienced person in this field who can help.